# HttpClient: Can i safely reuse HttpContext for different domains by multiple threads?

Tags: java, httpclient, apache-httpclient-4.x

Can i safely reuse HttpClientContext to store cookies for different domains by multiple threads, or perhaps it's better to create one context for each domain, or even narrower, create one context for each thread per domain ?

What i imagine is to behave like a browser that can handle cookies for each domains and which can open multiple tabs on pages that originates from the same or different domains.

Here's how i initiate the context only once to be reusable by multiple threads :

```
HttpClientContext context = HttpClientContext.create();
context.setCookieStore(this.createCookieStore());
```

I'm also using the latest version of the HttpClient.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you can not. Even though `HttpClientContext` instance itself is tread-safe it may contain context attributes that are not.

You however can safely make different `HttpClientContext` instances share the same `CookieStore` instance and therefore the same HTTP state.

Comment: That explains why i get random redirections urls from httpContext, which is caused by multithreaded usage. Now everything is working great. Thanks !